# How to get the current anchor/_fragment in twig

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, anchor

I have a page with 3 anchors (named a, b and c)
When i access this page i can have

- http://local/personne/1#a
- http://local/personne/1#b
- http://local/personne/1#c

As you can imagine, my page display some personne data and i also have a quick navigator to navigate to the next user.

I would like this quick navigator to keep the current anchor (or at least the anchor the page was loaded with)

I know about '_fragment' stuff in symfony, and i think it can bu use for my 'at least' solution

```
<a href="{{ path('next_personne', {'id': personne.id, '_fragment': 'TODO get current fragment here'}) }}">
          {{ personne.name }}
</a>
```

So if we access

- http://local/personne/1#a ==> http://local/personne/2#a
- http://local/personne/1#b ==> http://local/personne/2#b
- http://local/personne/1#c ==> http://local/personne/2#c

And if possible, the solution i would like to implement:

If we access the page using http://local/personne/1#a, it will render the url for next personne as http://local/personne/2#a. And if we click so that the anchor change to b, the url of the 'next' button will change to b also. I guess this would require some JS.

So basically if you know how to get the current anchor in twig or / and in JS, it would probably solve my problem.

Comment: You don't. URL fragments are not sent to the server. U'll need to resort to javascript

Comment: Maybe [FOS JsRouting](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, as DarkBee said, it's seems only JS can resolve this issue.

And Jquery provide some stuff to easily do that (see https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeHash(){
        $('.add-fragment').each(function () {
            let _fragment = window.location.hash.substr(1);
            let href = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[0];
            $(this).attr('href', href+'#'+_fragment);

        })
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        changeHash();
        window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){changeHash();}, false);
    });
</script>
```

Basically on change I add the hash to all links with class add-fragment, and on change i redo the same work.

This solve my entire problem.